# Adding str to every item in list python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

**Introduction**

Since im starting to get familiar with scrapy, i try to crawl some links out of random webpages.

**Problem**

The links im saving to my items.py file, are written without: "https://", but i need them as a hyperlink.

So i want to add "https://" before the actual links, so its formatted to a hyperlink.

**My Code**

```py
    def parse_target_page(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//div[@class="text-center artikelbox"]')

        for a in card:
            items = LinkcollectItem()
            link = ('a/@href')
            items ['Title'] = a.xpath('.//h5[@class="title"]/a/text()').get()
            items ['Link'] = a.xpath('.//h5[@class="title"]/a/@href').get()
            yield items
```

I tried with insert my string at index 0, but it didnt work

My output should print all links as hyperlink in csv-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need only add `https://` for each link, you can do following:

```py
link = a.xpath('.//h5[@class="title"]/a/@href').get()
items ['Link'] =  "https://" + link if link else link
```

Comment: what problem/error? what you see in output with such changes?

Comment: sorry my bad, it worked fine. I forgot "]". thanks sir!